# docker環境でUSB接続を認識できない

Tags: ubuntu, docker, usb

docker環境でC++のプログラムを実行しようとしています。
ローカル環境では問題なく動いていたのですが、docker環境ではUSBに接続した機器が認識できません。
docker環境ではUSB接続のための設定があるのでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: docker usb でググると、設定があるようでした。http://www.itmedia.co.jp/enterprise/articles/1603/02/news031_2.html などがわかりやすく記載されていますね。

Comment: 過去の質問について質問したまま放置せず、（質問者さんの抱える問題ではなく）質問文に記載した内容が解決したのであれば、[回答の承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)を実行してください。問題が解決していないのであれば、質問文を補足し何を求めているのかを明確にしてください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

--privilegeで解決できました。ご協力ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

[tanalab さんが共有しているリンク](http://www.itmedia.co.jp/enterprise/articles/1603/02/news031_2.html) で、おそらくうまくいくだろうとは思っていますが、前提が必要だと思います。

上記のリンクでは、どうやっているかというと、 USB 接続のデバイスファイルをコンテナの中にマウントしてやることで解決しています。

これは、少なくとも、コンテナである linux と ホストである OS の間で、 /dev/ の取り扱い方が一致している必要があります。なので、ホスト OS が、例えば mac だったり Windows だったりすると、かなり面倒臭くなるのではないか、と思っています。原理的に、ホストがコンテナと同じ(あるいは互換性のある) linux カーネルを使っている場合は、たぶん上手くいくと思います。

Comment: 本当ですね。安易に考えていました。Docker fo Mac だと https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/faqs/#can-i-pass-through-a-usb-device-to-a-container にあるようにできないみたいですね。MacやWindowsでUSBのデバイスを利用する場合は、VirtualBoxなどにLinuxとDockerをインストールして利用したほうが扱いやすいのですね。勉強になります。